# PHPStorm: 'Go to declaration' on class names in string literals

Tags: string, declaration, phpstorm, literals, classname

I'm using PHPStorm EAP version PS-138.940.

I have code as follows:

```
Config(__NAMESPACE__."\ObjectsToIdentifiers")->oldTables = array('Modules\Old\Model\DeviceStock','Modules\Old\Model\ProductPack','Modules\Old\Model\SpareStock','Modules\Old\Model\ConsumStock');
```

The functionality is irrelevant in this case. Important are the entries in the array. These are fully qualified class names - the leading / is omitted, but adding it doesn't solve my problem. I want to be able to click inside one of the string literals, press Ctrl+B and be redirected to the class definition.

Note that this works in ExtJS (javascript framework) where a string literal like

```
"MyApp.namespace.view.MyComponent"
```

will take me there.

Is there any way to manually configure this or do I have to submit a feature request. If so, how can I do that?

**Update 1:**

I created a feature request on JetBrains Youtrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24262

Comment: You could do Alt+up to select the string, then Command+O. A little more work, but palatable. I don't think PhpStorm recognises classes in strings as of yet.

Comment: *"Is there any way to manually configure this"* AFAIK this is not currently supported by IDE. *"or do I have to submit a feature request."* -- yes please (I would vote) -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: @deceze That would be Ctrl+W and Ctrl+N on Windows and Linux, thanks. But it doesn't work smoothly, because the selection encompasses the quotes which hinders the class search to recognize it. But marking the string is still better than manually searching the file.

Comment: @LazyOne I created a feature request. See the link in my edited post.

Comment: So any news on this? I see an earlier similar request from 2011 still marked as "to be discussed": https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5429. My guess it's too hard to implement, there is no way for the IDE to know if you're going to output the string or use it for dispatching. PHP just sucks sometimes. :(

Comment: It appears this feature was done on 1/14/17 according to the issue linked in "Update 1" above.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question looking for something in Storm that would let me quickly convert `"\Some\ClassName"` to `Some\ClassName::class` like an Intention or plugin, but so far have found nothing.

i'm surprised the `::class` static property hasn't been mentioned. It produces the FQN of the Class, and resolves from import aliases.

The following should be a legit rewrite that the IDE can resolve:

```php
// Same __NAMESPACE__, so no prefix needed
Config(ObjectsToIdentifiers::class)
    ->oldTables = [
        Modules\Old\Model\DeviceStock::class,
        Modules\Old\Model\ProductPack::class,
        Modules\Old\Model\SpareStock::class,
        Modules\Old\Model\ConsumStock::class
    ];

// or, if you import the classes:
use Modules\Old\Model\DeviceStock as OldDeviceStock;
// you can refer to
OldDeviceStock::class;
```

Unfortunately, right now if you jump-to-definition of the alias, Storm won't take you to the actual class, but where the alias is defined. Not *terribly* helpful, but gets you halfway since the actual class is right there.